# How to change wordpress meta title without changing page name

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to change the wordpress meta title (without altering the displayed page title, but only the title printed in the browser tab) in the admin section, so that, for example, when i edit a page, instead of having `Edit Page ‹ Website — WordPress` i have something like `Edit Page ‹ Contacts`.

I've added a little filter in the functions.php file to test it, but i have some issues. This is the code i have so far:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );

function filter_function_name( $title, $sep ) {
    echo "test title | ";
}
```

Now, from the code above, the result is having test title appended before the title. If i change the code to

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );

function filter_function_name( $title, $sep ) {
    $title = "test title | ";
}
```

I'm expecting the title to be only `test title |` but unfortunately it is not overwritten by the new variable at all and i don't really know why. other than that, i need to be able to change the title only on the admin side, but at the moment it doesn't seam to work on the admin side but only on the front end, is it because to filter the admin titles i need to use a different hook?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: use any seo plugin so u can easy to manage all pages meta details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878187/changing-wp-title-from-inside-my-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) the function should return a filtered title:

```
 @param string $title Default title text for current view.
 @param string $sep Optional separator.
 @return string Filtered title.
```

Now you're just creating a string variable – not returning it.

> I'm expecting the title to be only test title |

Then you need to **return** the string `test title |` :

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );

function filter_function_name( $title, $sep ) {
    return "test title | ";
}
```